# pandas: groupby apply using numba

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, numba, bodo

Using pandas v1.1.0.

In the pandas docs there is a nice example on how to use numba to speed up a `rolling.apply()` operation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#numba-jit-compilation)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def mad(x):
    return np.fabs(x - x.mean()).mean()

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.randn(100_000)},
                  index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100_000, freq='T')
).cumsum()

df.rolling(10).apply(mad, engine="numba", raw=True)
```

I would like to adapt it to work for a groupby operation:

```
df['day'] = df.index.day
df.groupby('day').agg(mad)
```

works fine.

But

```
df.groupby('day').agg(mad, engine='numba')
```

errors and gives

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NumbaUtilError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-ee23f1eec685> in <module>
----> 1 df.groupby('day').agg(mad, engine='numba')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ds-cit-dev\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    939 
    940         if maybe_use_numba(engine):
--> 941             return self._python_agg_general(
    942                 func, *args, engine=engine, engine_kwargs=engine_kwargs, **kwargs
    943             )

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ds-cit-dev\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_agg_general(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
   1068 
   1069             if maybe_use_numba(engine):
-> 1070                 result, counts = self.grouper.agg_series(
   1071                     obj,
   1072                     func,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ds-cit-dev\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in agg_series(self, obj, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    623 
    624         if maybe_use_numba(engine):
--> 625             return self._aggregate_series_pure_python(
    626                 obj, func, *args, engine=engine, engine_kwargs=engine_kwargs, **kwargs
    627             )

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ds-cit-dev\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in _aggregate_series_pure_python(self, obj, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    681 
    682         if maybe_use_numba(engine):
--> 683             numba_func, cache_key = generate_numba_func(
    684                 func, engine_kwargs, kwargs, "groupby_agg"
    685             )

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ds-cit-dev\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\util\numba_.py in generate_numba_func(func, engine_kwargs, kwargs, cache_key_str)
    215     nopython, nogil, parallel = get_jit_arguments(engine_kwargs)
    216     check_kwargs_and_nopython(kwargs, nopython)
--> 217     validate_udf(func)
    218     cache_key = (func, cache_key_str)
    219     numba_func = NUMBA_FUNC_CACHE.get(

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ds-cit-dev\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\util\numba_.py in validate_udf(func)
    177         or udf_signature[:min_number_args] != expected_args
    178     ):
--> 179         raise NumbaUtilError(
    180             f"The first {min_number_args} arguments to {func.__name__} must be "
    181             f"{expected_args}"

NumbaUtilError: The first 2 arguments to mad must be ['values', 'index']
```

I'm guessing with `engine=numba` it expects the data to be slightly different.

Comment: Original link of pandas doc is down. Here is the new link [Numba (JIT compilation)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#numba-jit-compilation)

Answer (score 4):

Had this problem myself. Apparently, to use pandas + numba engine you are *required* to implement custom functions in the format of `f(value, index)`.

as per the documentation (GroupBy.transform):

> If the 'numba' engine is chosen, the function must be a user defined
> function with values and index as the first and second arguments
> respectively in the function signature. Each group’s index will be
> passed to the user defined function and optionally available for use.

I had a simple function `f(x)` returning an `int` that I wanted to use inside a groupby. All it took to make it work with numba was amending the function to be `f(values, index)` so that the numba routine would have a valid parameter to pass the index to the function.

previous function (works fine, but not with numba):

```
def equal_weight(arr) -> int:
    '''
    returns a float of 1/n where 'n' is the number of rows
    '''
    return 1 / len(arr)
```

new function, compatible with numba engine:

```
def equal_weight(values, index) -> int:
    '''
    returns a float of 1/n where 'n' is the number of rows
    '''
    return 1 / len(values)
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried Bodo for this? It's built on top of Numba and supports Pandas directly. For example:

```
pip install bodo
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import bodo

def mad(x):
    return np.fabs(x - x.mean()).mean()

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.randn(100_000)},
                  index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100_000, freq='T')
).cumsum()

@bodo.jit(distributed=False)
def f(df):
    df['day'] = df.index.day
    df2 = df.groupby('day').agg(mad)
    return df2

df2 = f(df)
print(df2)
```

This example seems too small to benefit from compilation but this may help your real use case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df.groupby('day').agg(mad(df.groupby(day)), engine='numba')
```

Not sure about it  but it's saying the 1st 2 arguments must be `["values", 'index']`  I think it'll work with the dataframe.

Comment: Tried `g = df.groupby('day')` then `g.agg(mad(g), engine='numba')` and got `Traceback ...
ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 31`